# batch windows 7: loop to read a text file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, text-files

I have a text file like that:

> info1 subinfo1
>
> info2 subinfo2
>
> info3 subinfo3

I have to perform a loop on command using these infos.
I do it like that:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%cd%\%SCANS%) do (
        set stack=%%a
        set orientation=%%b 
        command1 -i test -o test -option1 %stack% -option2 %orientation%
)
```

It doesn't work. the option are always the same.

and Indeed if I do:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%cd%\%SCANS%) do (
set stack=%%a
set orientation=%%b   
echo %%a
echo %%b
echo %stack%
echo %orientation%
)
```

I have this:

> info1_lr
>
> axial
>
> info2_lr
>
> sagittal
>
> info3_lr
>
> coronal
>
> info2_lr
>
> sagittal
>
> info2_lr
>
> sagittal
>
> info2_lr
>
> sagittal

Is that normal ?

Comment: why don't you use `command1 -i test -o test -option1 %%a -option2 %%b` ?

Comment: because I have hundreds of line behind and for other to read the code it's more convenient if I can give variable name more informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is how I did:

```
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%cd%\%SCANS%) do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set stack=%%a
        set orientation=%%b 
        echo %%a
        echo %%b
        echo !stack!
        echo !orientation!
        endlocal
)
```

after looking at delayed expression
and it almost works for me.

except that I have a conflict with a way to "increment" a variable:

```
set cmdIntensityNLM=%cmdIntensityNLM% -i %RESULTS%/!stack!_blabla_%ITER%.nii.gz -o %RESULTS%/!stack!_blabla_%ITER%.nii.gz
```

I add to change it to:

```
set cmdIntensityNLM=!cmdIntensityNLM! -i %RESULTS%/!stack!_blabla_%ITER%.nii.gz -o %RESULTS%/!stack!_blabla_%ITER%.nii.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Absolutely.

Please use the search facility to find out about `delayed expansion` on Stack Overflow. The reasoning and solution will be there - it's a question that's been answered hundreds of times.

Comment: I have a conflict using delayed expansion then. set variable = %variable% ect !stack! etc ... doesn't work using delayed expansion. I have either !stack! either set variable = %variable% which works. I don't find a solution to have both and be able to increment my variable using the stack and orientation information

Comment: Sorry - I don't have a clear idea of what you are trying to achieve.